# Laravel 4 putting controller in subfolder - not finding class

Tags: class, laravel-4, controller, subdirectory

I have one controller in a subfolder which works perfect:

route:

```
Route::resource('json/stock/equipmentImages', 'Stock_EquipmentImageController');
```

getting its class from controller/stock/EquipmentImageController.php
which has a class definition:

```
class Stock_EquipmentImageController extends \BaseController {
```

The strangest thing happens if I do the same with:

```
Route::resource('json/stock/equipmentLocations', 'Stock_EquipmentLocationController')
```

Then I get the message, class not found.

If I move the class from controller/stock/EquipmentLocationController.php to
controller/EquipmentLocationController.php and adjust the route to:

```
Route::resource('json/stock/equipmentLocations', 'EquipmentLocationController');
```

Everything works.  This happens on a shared server without command line access. On my localhost all controllers can be put into a subfolder.

Comment: that's probably caused by namespace ? what is the namespace of 'EquipmentLocationController' ??

Comment: Namespacing and controller naming are probably an issue here but it sounds like the main problem might be due to case sensitivity on your Linux server when compared to your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using namespace which worked fine on my local host but gave issues on my public server. Namespacing everything DID solve the issues as suggested by egig. Thanks.

Here's what I did, in case others have similar issues:

I went through this nice tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAzd7Ig1Wgg
to get familiar with namespacing, as this is relative new for me in for Laravel 4.

router setup (resource router):

```
Route::resource('json/stock/equipment', 'App\Controllers\Stock\EquipmentController');
```

Added the psr 0 setting to autoload: (instead of using classmap) like the video suggests.

```
,
    "psr-0": {
        "Stock": "app/controllers/"
    } ....
```

Did not add anything to the basecontroller (no namespacing description):

```
    class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){ ....
```

Added namespacing and dependencies  to my controller in subfolder (controllers\stock):

```
namespace App\Controllers\Stock;
use BaseController, Form, Input, Redirect, View, Equipment, Response;

class EquipmentController extends BaseController { ....
```

Then placed my models in a subfolder (models\stock), without namespacing discription.

```
class Equipment extends \Eloquent {


protected $fillable = [

                'description',
                'location',
 ....
```

Then I did 'php artisan dump-autoload' and uploaded everything to my public server, changed database and public folder settings accordingly, because they are different. And everything worked!

Feedback is welcome, thanks for the support!